# Is there an official Raspberry Pi site for computer scientists?

Tags: official-foundation

I understand that the official Raspberry Pi site is https://www.raspberrypi.org/.

But it's designed for children, which makes me feel awkward visiting it and scrolling through the children's themes. I also understand that many, if not most users of the Raspberry Pi are adults.

So, is there an official Raspberry Pi site for adults, where they can escape those children's themes on the official site?

Comment: What do you mean? Much of what RaspberryPi stands for is educational. In addition, there is a magazine that covers more advanced stuff.

Comment: The site looks like it's marketing to preschool grade children, like about age 4 or so

Comment: Adults would mainly use the forums.

Comment: Being "an adult" is it is somewhat subjective, as people who participate in public life may have noticed in certain contexts. For example, if I am an an engineer with decades of professional experience and you are a weekend warrior who thought the pi seemed interesting, I may sometimes tell you to grow up, do some homework, try to act like "an adult", etc., and hopefully you take that the right way. But it would also be understandable if you called me a jerk. Then where are we? The foundation site is over the top friendly/happy (aka childish), but would you prefer it the other way around?

Comment: Hey, I know! Use your precious market freedom and buy something else. That'll teach them!

Comment: Not sure what is more immature, your attitude or their design choices. The Pi is a product designed for learning, not seasoned (electrical) engineers. It's designed to be very approachable by anyone and help take your first steps into the world of creating things. If you look for some super hardcore "nerdy" electronics website, you might be looking at the wrong product.

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand your discomfort with the main site. It may be a little juvenile, but there's nothing inappropriate about you using it. The Raspberry Pi was designed for a young demographic, and its official materials will reflect that. It doesn't make sense for them to have a separate, adult themed site. That would just a tremendous headache for all involved.

There is an [official forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/) which doesn't have the kid friendly themeing and the [MagPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/). Unofficially, you have this site, the entirety of the StackExchange network, plus the magic knowledge machine known as Google. I'm not sure what else you could need.

Comment: "a little juvenile" is a huge understatement (unless the British, Australians etc. are seeing different imagery than I do here in the USA)  I fully understand that Raspberry Pi is marketing to juveniles.  But, as a consumer, I was hoping to find a homepage that isn't saturated with childish images.  So, in the spirit of "Supply and Demand" and "Free Enterprise" I'm voicing my consumer preferences in the hopes vendors will respond with the products, services and yes Homepages that I prefer.  Do you think it's possible that the homepages have different themes based on region like Wikipedia does?

Comment: It is targeted at juveniles.  It is the raison d'etre of the charity.  If you look a bit more deeply you will probably find the information you need.

Comment: @user12711: I'm from the US, and everything I see is cartoony. The product is made and designed for children. You're either going to have to get over that, or use a different source to get your information. You can complain to the foundation if you really want to, but it seems rather puerile.

Comment: I'll continue to voice my consumer preferences and ask important questions like this one, because that's what makes Free Enterprise actually work WELL.  If consumers don't voice a Demand, there certainly won't ever be a Supply.  So everyone, including consumer kids that don't like being treated like toddlers, should voice their preferences to suppliers.  Educational lesson for all the babies reading now:  This isn't the USSR.  We ask for the products and services we want in free nations.

Comment: You're free to do whatever you want; I really don't care. As I stated though, you should make your request to the foundation, either in email or on **their** forum. This site isn't run by them and I doubt they pay much attention to it. All I said was that you're unlikely to get what you want.